# How to extract filename + extension only from full path in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, split, filepath

Filepaths returned from the API look like this:

`https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/media/private/files/Corp%20Data%20Collection.pdf?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIA6FUWELJHGJHGLIJI4Hss2F20191204%2Fca-central-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20191204T185901Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=2a227681a180d8785be4edfa9e15dkjhsdkjs8796937182d9c33fc12a0e52affe97`

I would like to extract filename and extension and also replace any ASCII expressions like %20. So the end result returned should be:

`Corp_Data_Collection.pdf`

any thoughts on how to get this done in Javascript?

Comment: `unescape(strPath.split("?")[0].split("/").pop())`

Comment: @dandavis this works! please put in an answer so I can accept it as the solution.

Comment: One function does all that ?

Comment: yes, that worked for me.

Comment: `file = file_path.replace(/^(?:[^\/?]*\/)*([^\/?]*).*/g, function(a,b) { return unescape(b); });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I ended up with:

file = file_path.replace(/^(?:[^/?]*/)*([^/?]*).*/g, function(a,b) { return unescape(b); });

Comment: The solution that should be used `file = file_path.replace(/^(?:[^\/?]*\/)*([^\/?]*).*/g, function(a,b) { return unescape(b); });` Faster because it doesn't split all over the place.

Answer (score 3):

You can JavaScript's `URL` constructor to get the pathname from the URL like so:

```
const url = new URL("https://yourlongurl.com/something/yourfile.pdf");
const pathname = url.pathname;
```

From the pathname, you can then extract the last part of it using `substring` like so:

```
const filename = unescape(pathname.substring(pathname.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
```

This will return `"yourfile.pdf"`

Comment: Thanks, this works, although I needed to unescape the final expression. I ended up using @dandavis solution as it is more elegant as a one-liner.

Comment: You should also use `unescape` or `decodeURIComponent` on the result.

Comment: Sure, I'll add in an `unescape`  :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let link =
    "https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/media/private/files/Corp%20Data%20Collection.pdf?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIA6FUWELJHGJHGLIJI4Hss2F20191204%2Fca-central-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20191204T185901Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=2a227681a180d8785be4edfa9e15dkjhsdkjs8796937182d9c33fc12a0e52affe97";

let regex = link.match(/.+?(?=\?)/)[0].split("/");

console.log(decodeURIComponent(regex[regex.length - 1]));
// Corp Data Collection.pdf
```

```
/.+?(?=\?)/
```

This regex will match anything until the char "?" is found (excluding this character).

Then, get the first matching element and split the string in arrays (using "/").

Then, decode the last element of the array

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna do it explicitly with RegEx you can use this RegEx:
`\/([^\/]*\.[^\/]*)\?`

`\/` matches a (forward-)slash literally.

`[^\/]*` matches everything but a slash for 0+ times.

`\.` matches a `.` literally.

The parentheses around `[^\/]*\.[^\/]*` make a group out of this match.

`\?` matches a `?` literally.

You could use this JS-code:

```
const regex = /\/([^\/]*\.[^\/]*)\?/gm;
const str = `https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/media/private/files/Corp%20Data%20Collection.pdf?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIA6FUWELJHGJHGLIJI4Hss2F20191204%2Fca-central-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20191204T185901Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=2a227681a180d8785be4edfa9e15dkjhsdkjs8796937182d9c33fc12a0e52affe97`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```